# Mongoose/mongoDB query joins.. but I come from a sql background

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I coming from a sql background so writing queries in sql where I join tables is quite simple but I guess I am missing that in mongoose/mongodb

Basically I know the Subscriber_ID (which maps to a document in the User Collection)

I want to pull the project group, with all the projects that the user belongs to so if I was to write this in pseduo sql it would be like

```
Select 
  ProjectGroup.title, 
  Project.Title 
FROM 
  ProjectGroup, 
  Project, 
  User 
WHERE 
  User.id = req.body.subscriber_id 
  AND Project.subscriber_id = User.id 
  AND  ProjectGroup.project_id = Project.id
```

There must be a way to do similiar joins in mongoose/mongodb because the type is mapping to a schema right?

My Schemas.....

Project Group Schema

```
var ProjectGroupSchema = new Schema({
    title             : String
  , projects          : [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project' } ]
});
```

Project Schema

```
var ProjectSchema = new Schema({
    title         : {type : String, default : '', required : true}
  , subscribers   : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});
```

User Schema

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    first_name    : {type: String, required: true}
  , last_name     : {type: String, required: true}
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You are just one step away!

Project Group Schema:

```
var ProjectGroupSchema = new Schema({
    title             : String
});
```

Project Schema:

```
var ProjectSchema = new Schema({
    title         : {type : String, default : '', required : true},
    group         : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProjectGroup' },
    _users    : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});
```

User Schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    first_name    : {type: String, required: true},
    last_name     : {type: String, required: true},
    subscribing   : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project' }]
});
```

Then you can do the following:

```
user.findById(req.userId)
     .populate('subscribing')
     .exec(function(err, user){
          console.log(user.subscribing);
     })
```

Or:

```
project.find({
        subscriber : req.userId
      })
     .populate('subscriber')
     .populate('group')
     .exec(function(err, projects){
          console.log(projects);
     })
```

Comment: Very interesting I will apply this and see how it works but the second one you mention looks like exactly what I need.

Comment: Okay I just updated my schema references and used these populates works perfectly!

Comment: This is awesome, but can you modify the return result from the exec, say if i dont want to include group field.

Comment: I am a bit at a loss for how it knows what to "join" on where. Is that what the `ref` property is for? Does mongoose's `populate` look for `ProjectSchema` based upon the ref being `Project`, and does that mean that a strict naming convention needs to be kept?

Comment: God answer !! very clever

Answer (score 4):

There are no joins in Mongodb. This question I think is a good reference:

[MongoDB and "joins"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067197/mongodb-and-joins)

To summarize, different strategies have to be adopted with mongodb for problems that would be addressed via joins in relational DBs. I would say you mainly end-up doing one of these two things:

- Embedding: You embed information in a single document that would in a relational DB be distributed amongst different tables.
- Joining information client-side: When you need to use information from several places, you query many times and then put the pieces together in your client.

Comment: Yeah that is a great post at explaining it... now just time to implement!