# MEAN Stack: junction tables

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-schema, junction-table

I'm new in Mean Stack workflow and my background relays on MySql schemas.

I'm creating a little application to improve my skills on it, and I've encountered a logic question.

I've created two Schemas: a User schema and a Ticket schema.
Now I've to save extra info in the relation between the two Schemas: in MySql, I used junction tables (**user_tickets** in Laravel case) where I could store, for example, when a user opens a ticket, or if a user hides a ticket and so on...

In Mongoose and in Mean Stack world I can't find a solution.
Now I've created a third model **UserTickets** but it's problematic and expensive to maintain the third model.

Am I wrong?
Is there another simpler method?

Answer (score 1):

I think that embedded documents (Mongoose Sub Docs) can be a good solution for you.
Maybe this can help you:

[Mongoose Sub Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

[MongoDB and joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067197/mongodb-and-joins)

[MongoDB Joins with MongooseJS](http://start.jcolemorrison.com/mongodb-joins-with-mongoosejs/)

[Mongoose/mongoDB query joins.. but I come from a sql background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363065/mongoose-mongodb-query-joins-but-i-come-from-a-sql-background)