# How to assign some values to fields of documents from mongodb before passing it to client on Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is code that send array of cards to client.

```
var cards = Card.find().sort('-created').exec(function (err, cards) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {
        res.json(cards);
    }
});
```

Model Card have a field "ownerName" (it's empty in database) and "ownerId" (id of some user). For each card I need to find a user by card.ownerId and assign its name to field "ownerName". How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to do it properly and use [refs and population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var cardSchema = Schema({
  _id: Number,
  owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
});

var Card =  mongoose.model('Card', cardSchema);
var cards = Card.find()
  .sort('-created')
  .populate('owner')
  .exec(function (err, cards) {
    //all cards have a 'owner' field populated with the referenced user doc
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you already have a `User` model.If its the case, the just use "sql-join-like" between your `Card` model and `User` model as described here [Mongoose/mongoDB query joins.. but I come from a sql background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363065/mongoose-mongodb-query-joins-but-i-come-from-a-sql-background?answertab=active#tab-top).

The "join column" would be `ownerId`.

Once you get a list of your cards and users, you will be able to assign the user's name to the field `ownerName`.