# Can we retrive data of two tables in nodejs with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am working one project there is some relational concept so i want to retrieve data from two different tables in same query , can i do this ? i am following below link but i am not getting exact that i wants.
[Mongoose/mongoDB query joins.. but I come from a sql background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363065/mongoose-mongodb-query-joins-but-i-come-from-a-sql-background)

I have also review this links

https://start.jcolemorrison.com/mongodb-joins-with-mongoosejs/

I have review this mongoose links, here i am getting something positive.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

What i have done so far is like below:
Create Models for project and project_category and try to get all project with category details. I have update my code at below link to review :

https://www.protectedtext.com/rushabhcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mongooses have populate in built function to join two table

in schema just add ref for linking table

suppose you want to join two table 
table 1 :**User**
table 2 :**posts**

in posts schema add

```
posted_by: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
```

and the time of query just add populate

suppose

```
postModel.find({}).populate({path:'posted_by'}).exec(function(err,response){


})
```

this will help you get all post value with user details who has posted