# Get info from another collection based of _id and merge - MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections. Lets call one `baskets` and the other one `fruits`.

In `baskets` we have the following document:

```
[{
    basket_name: "John's Basket",
    items_in_basket: [
        {
            fruit_id: 1,
            comment: "Delicious!"
        },
        {
            fruit_id: 2,
            comment: "I did not like this"
        }
    ]
}]
```

And in `fruits` we have the following documents:

```
[{
    _id: 1,
    fruit_name: "Strawberry",
    color: "Red"
},
{
    _id: 2,
    fruit_name: "Watermelon",
    color: "Green"
}]
```

How do I get information on each fruit in `John's Basket`?

The result should look like this:

```
[{
    fruit_id: 1,
    comment: "Delicious!",
    fruit_name: "Strawberry",
    color: "Red"
},
{
    fruit_id: 2,
    comment: "I did not like this",
    fruit_name: "Watermelon",
    color: "Green"  
}]
```

Comment: There's no "join" in MongoDB. You either could consider using a MapReduce function to create a new structure, or write the code necessary to fetch each `fruit` instance on demand and merge it in your client code with a `basket` document. You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067197/mongodb-and-joins) Q/A helpful.

Comment: @WiredPrairie: this should be an answer not a comment, i would upvote that ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no "join" in MongoDB. You either could:

- consider using a MapReduce function to create a new structure that contains the merged data
- write the code necessary to fetch each `fruit` instance on demand and merge it in your client code with a `basket` document.
- denormalize the data and include the details for each fruit in the `basket` document. This poses it's own set of issues as data is duplicated and updates to a particular `fruit` would then need to be made to every usage in the collection.

Both have their pros and cons.

You might find this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067197/mongodb-and-joins) helpful, and also [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/) documentation for MongoDB.

Answer (score 3):

this is no longer true.

Since version 3.2, MongoDB added the $lookup command.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

```
db.orders.insert([
   { "_id" : 1, "item" : "almonds", "price" : 12, "quantity" : 2 },
   { "_id" : 2, "item" : "pecans", "price" : 20, "quantity" : 1 },
   { "_id" : 3  }
])

db.inventory.insert([
   { "_id" : 1, "sku" : "almonds", description: "product 1", "instock" : 120 },
   { "_id" : 2, "sku" : "bread", description: "product 2", "instock" : 80 },
   { "_id" : 3, "sku" : "cashews", description: "product 3", "instock" : 60 },
   { "_id" : 4, "sku" : "pecans", description: "product 4", "instock" : 70 },
   { "_id" : 5, "sku" : null, description: "Incomplete" },
   { "_id" : 6 }
])


db.orders.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "inventory",
         localField: "item",
         foreignField: "sku",
         as: "inventory_docs"
       }
  }
])
```

returns:

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "item" : "almonds",
   "price" : 12,
   "quantity" : 2,
   "inventory_docs" : [
      { "_id" : 1, "sku" : "almonds", "description" : "product 1", "instock" : 120 }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 2,
   "item" : "pecans",
   "price" : 20,
   "quantity" : 1,
   "inventory_docs" : [
      { "_id" : 4, "sku" : "pecans", "description" : "product 4", "instock" : 70 }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 3,
   "inventory_docs" : [
      { "_id" : 5, "sku" : null, "description" : "Incomplete" },
      { "_id" : 6 }
   ]
}
```

Comment: you can't use `$lookup` on sharded collections. Use it only if your collections are unsharded. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633111/mongodb-to-use-sharding-with-lookup-aggregation-operator has a better solution for sharded collections.