# Mongoose populate vs aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've noticed that .populate function in mongoose 4.7.3 runs separate queries on the database for each lookup:

```
  db.House
    .populate('ownerId')
    .exec((err, result) => {
    ..
```

With aggregation pipeline we can lookup multiple collections with a single query:

```
    db.House.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
      {
        from: 'owners',
        localField: 'ownerId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'owner',
      },
```

What is the reason for mongoose to do separate queries with .populate? Is the aggregation function more performant on lookups?

Comment: The `populate()` functionality in Mongoose is a client-side query aggregation feature that predates the addition of server-side `$lookup` support in MongoDB 3.2.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's a summary of the differences:

`$lookup`

- can only be used with `aggregate`
- can only be used to pull in referenced documents from [unsharded collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#sharded-collection-restrictions)
- can pull in referenced documents by any field
- generally more performant as it's a server-side operation
- requires MongoDB 3.2+

Mongoose `populate()`

- can be used with `find` and `aggregate`
- can be used to to pull in referenced documents from both sharded and unsharded collections
- can only pull in referenced documents by `_id`
- no MongoDB version requirement

Comment: I'm wondering... did I read the [mongoddb manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-sharded-collections/) wrong? I found information that aggregate works on sharded dbs as well.

Comment: @AdrianMoisa `aggregate` can, but not `$lookup`. I added a link to the docs for that.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Just found this interesting [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633111/mongodb-to-use-sharding-with-lookup-aggregation-operator). Same point as you made.

Comment: Can I not .populate() by something other than _id?
I thought you could set a virtual on your schema by providing a localField and foreignField (with ref to model) and .populate(). I guess I never tried, but I would imagine I could just set localField or foreignField to something other than  "_id"?