# Query with arbitrary number of filter conditions that come from querying the same collection

Tags: mongodb, performance, nosql, aggregation-framework, query-optimization

```js
const score_schema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    tester_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "user",
      required: true,
    },
    test_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "test",
      required: true,
    },
    score: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    collection: `score`,
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

query 1:

A user is given. First a query to the `score` model is made to find all tests that this user has taken.
This will result in an arbitrary number of tests and the score of each test.

query 2:

Another query is made to the `score` model to find all documents where the `test_id` matches the `test_id` returned from the above query
and where the score of each test is greater than or equal to the score of the `test_id` returned from the query above.

This essentially means that the arbitrary number of documents returned from `query 1` will be the number of filter conditions to `query 2`.

Problem:

Can the above 2 queries be combined into 1 query and thus one round trip to the MongoDB API? If not, then a solution of 2 separate queries is also acceptable.

```js
const dummy_data = [
  {
    tester_id: "1",
    test_id: "1",
    score: 40
  },
  {
    tester_id: "1",
    test_id: "2",
    score: 50
  },
   {
    tester_id: "1",
    test_id: "3",
    score: 70
  },
  {
    tester_id: "2",
    test_id: "1",
    score: 50
  },
  {
    tester_id: "3",
    test_id: "2",
    score: 20
  },
   {
    tester_id: "3",
    test_id: "3",
    score: 60
  },
  {
    tester_id: "7",
    test_id: "5",
    score: 40
  },
  {
    tester_id: "8",
    test_id: "4",
    score: 50
  },
   {
    tester_id: "9",
    test_id: "4",
    score: 70
  },
]
```

EDITED:

The output should have the same schema as the original collection, `score_schema`.

For example, given `tester_id` of `1`, the output should be:

```js
[
  {
    tester_id: "2",
    test_id: "1",
    score: 50
  }
]
```

Explanation:

The `tester_id` of `1` took a total of 3 tests. There is only one document where another `tester_id` took a test equaling to one of the three taken by `tester_id` of `1` and had a score greater than the score generated by `tester_id` of `1`.

The output should not include documents with the original `tester_id`. In this case, it is `tester_id` 1.

Comment: can you show, whatever you have tried and the expected result in JSON format as per your dummy data.

Comment: I do not know whether it is possible or not to combine them into 1 query, so I haven't been able to get started. The output would have the same schema as the Model itself. It would just be a subset of its documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.  (Comments are in the query.)

```js
db.score.aggregate([
  { // the tester of interest
    "$match": { "tester_id": "1" }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      // lookup by test_id
      "from": "score",
      "localField": "test_id",
      "foreignField": "test_id",
      "let": { "myId": "$tester_id", "myScore": "$score" },
      "pipeline": [
        { // only return docs of different tester
          // and higher score
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                { "$ne": [ "$tester_id", "$$myId" ] },
                { "$gt": [ "$score", "$$myScore" ] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "higherScores"
    }
  },
  { // only keep non-empty higherScores
    "$match": {
      "$expr": { "$gt": [ { "$size": "$higherScores" }, 0 ] }
    }
  },
  { // only field we care about now
    "$project": { "higherScores": 1 }
  },
  { // might be more than one
    "$unwind": "$higherScores"
  },
  { // hoist it to ROOT
    "$replaceWith": "$higherScores"
  },
  { // don't want _id
    "$unset": "_id"
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KuyEbL_Km4w).

Comment: This seems to be most promising. Will check thoroughly later and award bounty.

Comment: @freelionsntigersfromcages Full disclosure: This does not consider *multiple* entries of the *same* test by the given `tester_id` (here it's `"1"`).  This could be accommodated but you didn't specify that possibility.

Comment: that is not a requirement anyways, thanks. Each `tester_id` will only take a `test_id` once.

Comment: What if the `score` collection is sharded? Now it cannot be in the `$lookup` stage. Is there a solution for this scenario?

Comment: @freelionsntigersfromcages Have a look at [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633111/mongodb-to-use-sharding-with-lookup-aggregation-operator) and others for the case where sharding is present.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it without lookup is using `$group`, for example:

```
db.score.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$test_id",
      highestScore: {$max: "$score"},
      tester_id: {$push: "$tester_id"},
      results: {
        $push: {score: "$score", "tester_id": "$tester_id"}
      },
      ourTester: {
        $push: {score: "$score", "tester_id": "$tester_id"}
      }
    }
  },
  {$match: {"tester_id": userId}},
  {
    $project: {
      ourTester: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$ourTester",
          as: "item",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$item.tester_id", userId]}
        }
      },
      results: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$results",
          as: "item",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$item.score", "$highestScore"]}}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      ourTester: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$ourTester", 0]},
      highest: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$results", 0]}
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {$gt: ["$highest.score", "$ourTester.score"]}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      score: "$highest.score",
      tester_id: "$highest.tester_id",
      test_id: "$res._id"
    }
  }
])
```

As you can see [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lEAAH67K53z)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`aggregate`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/) query with [`$lookup`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "tester_id": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "let": {
        "score": "$score",
        "tester_id": "$tester_id"
      },
      "localField": "tester_id",
      "foreignField": "test_id",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              "$and": [
                {
                  $ne: [
                    "$tester_id",
                    "$$tester_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $gte: [
                    "$score",
                    "$$score"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        
      ],
      "as": "result"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$result"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": null,
      "result": {
        $push: "$result"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": {
      "$mergeObjects": "$result"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "score": 50,
    "test_id": "1",
    "tester_id": "2"
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q4Hnw-dYvmb)

Comment: It doesn't seem to take into the requirement that a specific `user_id` is given.

Comment: @freelionsntigersfromcages please check I have updated the answer you can pass the `user_id` in `$match`.

Comment: I don't think the output is correct. I have edited my post to include an example of the output and an explanation. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

**Here comes a detailed aggregation that handles the data**

*If I understood all the requirements correctly*

```
[{$facet: {
 tests_per_tester: [
  {
   $match: {
/***   select the tester here **/
    tester_id: '1'
   }
  },
  {
   $group: {
    _id: '$tester_id',
    tests: {
     $push: '$$ROOT'
    }
   }
  }
 ],
 scores_by_test: [
  {
   $group: {
    _id: '$test_id',
    scores: {
     $push: '$score'
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}}, {$unwind: {
 path: '$tests_per_tester'
}}, {$unwind: {
 path: '$tests_per_tester.tests'
}}, {$unwind: {
 path: '$scores_by_test'
}}, {$unwind: {
 path: '$scores_by_test.scores'
}}, {$match: {
 $expr: {
  $and: [
   {
    $eq: [
     '$tests_per_tester.tests.test_id',
     '$scores_by_test._id'
    ]
   },
   {
    $gte: [
     '$tests_per_tester.tests.score',
     '$scores_by_test.scores'
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
}}]
```

The $facet step divides the data into two categories: testers and tests, while the rest of the query is just a series of $unwinds and a $match to give the desired results.

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nw_XnPzhtyh)

Comment: You can reverse the relations by switching $gte with $lt.

Comment: this looks promising. How test it out soon

Comment: @lianToren I don't think the output is correct. I have edited my post to include an example of the output and an explanation. Please have a look.