# mongo data types: use a String for a Role or a custom model?

Tags: mongodb

So I have practically worked with relational databases only.

Now I'd like to do my first real project with mongo.
I need a role-based access to my app.

In a relational DB, I'd probably put a column 'role' in my 'user' table, having 'role' being referenced by a table of roles.

Maybe this is not quite right for a NOSQL db?
In other words, is it best practice to store the Role just as a string?
E.g.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
   username: { type: String, required: true },
   password: { type: String, required: true },
   role:     { type: String }
});
```

or would it be something like:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
       username: { type: String, required: true },
       password: { type: String, required: true },
       role:     { type: Role }
    });
```

(if that's possible at all)

Answer (score 1):

you could have another collection called authority that holds the different authoritys and their names as a string like :

```
 {
  "_id": ObjectId("51644d0884969b4512"),
  "authority": "ROLE_USER",
 }
```

and then your user-object has a field with a refference

```
 {
  "_id": ObjectId("5123432969d434553"),
  "password": "notSave",
  "name":"user0",
  "role:ObjectId("51644d0884969b4512")
 }
```

and your code would be sth like

```
   user = db.user.find({name:"user0"});
   userRole = db.authority.find({"_id":user.id})
```

but if you wanted to get all user with role admin for example, then you need to write iterative code

i made the experience that this can get very messy, especially while iterating over more collections with abstract querys, even with ensured indexes the runtime got longer and longer because sth like table-joins in a single query seems to be not possible, or i did not find out

nevertheless i like mongodb, maybe it helps you

nevertheless you can and you better avoid assosiated documents in other collections and store it in the same document
and as a string

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
   username: { type: String, required: true },
   password: { type: String, required: true },
   role:     { type: String }
});
```

[MongoDB and "joins"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067197/mongodb-and-joins)

Comment: Yeah...there's no point using a nosql db if you're using it as a relational db...as I want to make experiences with node and mongo, I'll use a String for the role, avoiding to have cross-references.