# How to perform matching between the documents of two different collection in mongodb and perform updation?

Tags: json, mongodb

Suppose I have two collections in Mongodb say Col_1 and Col_2.
Format for Col_1:

```
{
"_id":"",
"Field_1":"abc",
"Field_2":"color"
},
{

"_id":"",
"Field_1":"red"
"Field_2":"fruits"
}
```

And the format of Col_2 is:
 {

```
"_id":"",
"Field_1":"xyz abc orange red",
"Field_2":"799842",
"Field_3":""
}
```

{

```
"_id":"",
"Field_1":"xyz abc orange red",
"Field_2":"4743893",
"Field_3":""

}
```

I want to compare the field1 of Col_1 with the field1 of Col_2 and update the Field3 of Col_2 with the field2 of Col_1.

Suppose if we apply the find command and it returns with the matched documents I want to update those.Can I perform this on shell or I need to use some programming language?

Comment: MongoDB never support joins like `sql` so this not possible, either you should change your collection's structure. for more check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067197/mongodb-and-joins

Comment: So how can I implement this,is there any alternative?

Comment: there was no alternative, you should follow this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681851/mongodb-combine-data-from-multiple-collections-into-one-how

o.w. change your collections, create single collections instead of multiple collections.

Comment: ok.thanx If i put this in a single collection and then with a single query I would be able to find and update?

Comment: yes, if you have any problem in find and updating then you should post questions here. All are here  willing to help each other :)

Comment: @yogesh should I edit my question or post a new question?

Comment: Better way to post new questions with new collections and your problem.

Comment: @yogesh can you help here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29488115/how-to-perform-matching-inside-a-collection-in-mongodb-and-perform-updation-in-t