# How to perform matching inside a collection in mongodb and perform updation in the result set?

Tags: json, mongodb

Suppose I have a collection in Mongodb say Col_1
Format for Col_1:

```
{
"_id":"",
"Field_1":"abc",
"Field_2":"color"
},

{
"_id":"",
"Field_1":"red"
"Field_2":"fruits"
},

{ 
"_id":"",
"content":"xyz abc orange red",
"numbr":"799842",
"Field_3":""
}

{    
"_id":"",
"content":"xyz abc orange red",
"numbr":"4743893",
"Field_3":""  
}
```

This collection consist of data from two different json file.So I want to pick the field containing red and match with the field containing xyz abc orange red and then finally update the field3 which is left blank with the color and then same with abc and so on.
Is this possible with a query?or we have to write some program in python or any other language?

I want the output to be :

```
{
"_id":"",
"content":"xyz abc orange red",
"numbr":"4743893",
"Field_3":"fruit"  
},

{   
"_id":"",
"content":"xyz abc orange red",
"numbr":"4743893",
"Field_3":"color" 
},

{    
"_id":"",
"content":"xyz abc orange red",
"numbr":"4743893",
"Field_3":"fruit"   
}
```

Basically I have two types of data in my collection my aim is to update those arrays which have empty Field_3 with the Field_2 of different array after it matches that particular word say red,orange in the full sentence.

Comment: I did not understand  _"pick the field containing red and match with the field containing xyz abc orange red"_ . Also, in MongoDB you can perform all tasks using its Native Query. Drivers are there if you are making an application in a particular language (say JAVA) and want to perform everything in that language and don't want to perfrom native queries in MongoDB.

Comment: @dev suppose if you want to match the "xyz" in "abc xyz orangge" if it matches then it returns with all the results containing xyz  say -"abc xyz oraange","123 abx xyz" and so on.Now with the result set one field is empty I want to update that

Comment: @nik it's too complicated to understand what exactly you should want, or you should put your expected output here.

Comment: @nik: thanks for the edit. I do get it right that `_id` isn't really expected to be empty?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Correct that particular array whose Field_3 needs to be updated from Field_2 of different types of array