# How to return single object instead of array in $lookup of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

When we use `$lookup` in a*ggregate query* of **MongoDB** we use this format

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: "users",
       localField: "userId",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "user"
     }
}
```

where `user` return as an array of object and then some time we need to use `$arrayElemAt` in `$project` stage to return as a single object. like

```
{
  $project:
   {
    user:
      { 
        $arrayElemAt: [ "$user", 0 ] 
      }
   }
}
```

so my question is how can we return `user` as a **single object** instead of **array** from `$lookup` stage ?

Comment: [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) returns array. I doubt you can do any better than project it on next stage.

Comment: yes currently using `$project` on next stage but I have to projected 20+ fields also. It would be better if I could return single object  in `$lookup` @AlexBlex

Comment: It may seem better, but it is not. You assume the lookup matches exactly 1 element. It may be fair for your case, so the best place to keep this logic is in userspace - the next stage of the pipeline. When your application evolve to the point when this assumption do not hold anymore, you will be happy that you can change the query yourself and choose what to do if you have more than 1 matching element.

Comment: I believe, as @AlexBlex rightly pointed out, the docs explicitly states that [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) returns an array, nothing more nothing less. What you may want to do is open a JIRA feature request, I can happily upvote this.

Comment: thanks @chridam for your suggestion. created a feature request issue in JIRA https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27589

Answer (score 11):

You can't do that with `$lookup` yet, the cleanest way to do it would be to  add a new stage afterwards like this:

```
{
  $unwind: "$user"
}
```

Since each document has only one user you end up with the same collection but this time user is no longer an array. If you had more than one user per document (e.g 2), you would end up with 2 documents one with each user.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot return object as the output of `$lookup`, you can use the subsequent stage `$set` to overwrite the existing `'user'` field (similar to what you did with `$project`)

```
{$set: {'user': {$first: '$user'}}}
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Also, you can use `{$set: {'user': {$first: '$user.someField'}}}` to get just one field (my use case)